# All possible permutations columns Pandas Dataframe within the same column

Tags: python, pandas, permutation

I had a similar question using Postgres SQL, but I figured that this kind of task is really hard to do in Postgres, and I think python/pandas would make this a lot easier, although I still can't quite come up with the solution.

I now have a Pandas Dataframe which looks like this:

```
df={'planid' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'x' : ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2']}

df=pd.DataFrame(df)

df


   planid   x
0   A       a1
1   A       a2
2   B       b1
3   B       b2
4   C       c1
5   C       c2
```

I want to get all possible permutations where planid are not equal to each other. In other words, think of each value in planid as a "bucket" and I want all possible combinations if I were to draw values from `x` from each 
"bucket" in `planid`. In this particular example, there are 8 total permutations {(a1, b1, c1), (a1, b2, c1), (a1, b1, c2), (a1, b2, c2), (a2, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c1), (a2, b1, c2), (a2, b2, c2)}.

However, I want my resulting data frame to be three columns, `planid`, `x` and another column, perhaps named `permutation_counter`. The final data frame has all the different permutations labeled with `permutation_counter`. In other words, I want my final dataframe to look like

```
       planid   x  permutation_counter
    0   A       a1     1
    1   B       b1     1
    2   C       c1     1 
    3   A       a1     2
    4   B       b2     2
    5   C       c1     2
    6   A       a1     3
    7   B       b1     3
    8   C       c2     3
    9   A       a1     4
    10  B       b2     4
    11  C       c2     4
    12  A       a2     5
    13  B       b1     5
    14  C       c1     5
    15  A       a2     6
    16  B       b2     6
    17  C       c1     6
    18  A       a2     7
    19  B       b1     7
    20  C       c2     7
    21  A       a2     8
    22  B       b2     8
    23  C       c2     8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to chain as many steps together as possible. Break them down to see what each step does :)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([subdf['x'] for p, subdf in df.groupby('planid')], names=df.planid.unique())).reset_index().stack().reset_index()

df2.columns = ['permutation_counter', 'planid', 'x']
df2['permutation_counter'] += 1

print df2[['planid', 'x', 'permutation_counter']]

   planid   x  permutation_counter
0       A  a1                    1
1       B  b1                    1
2       C  c1                    1
3       A  a1                    2
4       B  b1                    2
5       C  c2                    2
6       A  a1                    3
7       B  b2                    3
8       C  c1                    3
9       A  a1                    4
10      B  b2                    4
11      C  c2                    4
12      A  a2                    5
13      B  b1                    5
14      C  c1                    5
15      A  a2                    6
16      B  b1                    6
17      C  c2                    6
18      A  a2                    7
19      B  b2                    7
20      C  c1                    7
21      A  a2                    8
22      B  b2                    8
23      C  c2                    8
```

Answer (score 2):

@Happy001 beat me by a couple of minutes but I'll go ahead and post this anyway because I think it's a little easier to follow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

x = list( itertools.product( ['a1','b2'],['b1','b2'],['c1','c2'] ) )
x = list( itertools.chain(*x) )
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'planid'  : np.tile( list('ABC'), 8 ),
                    'x'       : x,
                    'p_count' : np.repeat( range(1,9), 3 ) })
```

results:

```
    p_count planid   x
0         1      A  a1
1         1      B  b1
2         1      C  c1
3         2      A  a1
4         2      B  b1
5         2      C  c2

...

21        8      A  b2
22        8      B  b2
23        8      C  c2
```

Comment: Hey JohnE. This is a bit easier to follow, but in my real case, I actually have a lot of values and won't be able to specify 'a1', 'b2', etc. out explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Vincent -- Sure, hope it helps.  I suspect it could be generalized to handle your situation, but it's not obvious to me how your sample data is going to map to your actual data.  Happy001 handled this in a clever way (using groupby with from_product), hopefully that also works for your real data but I wasn't sure it would.  Actually, both our answers do essentially the same thing so you could certainly mix and match pieces of each.