# Find permutations in a huge pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, permutation

I have quite a large dataframe that looks basically as follows:

```
df_apple = pd.DataFrame({'_id': ['A','B' ,'C'], 'apple': ['1', '0', '1'], 'orange': ['1', '1', '0'],  'kiwi': ['1', '0', '1']})
```

I have columns with features and a binary classifcation per `_id`. I am trying to find the frequency and total count of all individuals (`_id`) for each permutation/combination of `apple`, `orange`, and `kiwi`. This is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518308/all-possible-permutations-columns-pandas-dataframe-within-the-same-column).

In this toy-case, the combination `apple`, `orange`, and `kiwi` appears one time (`_id == A`), whilst the combination `apple == 0 & orange==1 & kiwi==0` appears not at all.

I am trying to create a output that should contain the following inforamation:

```
df_combination = pd.DataFrame({'_id': ['Apple, Orange and Kiwi','Only Orange' ,'Apple and Kiwi but not Orang'], 'Count': ['1', '1', '1']})
```

i.e. a dataframe telling me, which combination is found and how often. I am not interested in combinations that do not appear at all.

However, My dataframe has roughly 300 columns. I cannot specify them a priori and computationally solving this would take ages. Any ideas how to solve this in a good way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All possible permutations columns Pandas Dataframe within the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518308/all-possible-permutations-columns-pandas-dataframe-within-the-same-column)

Comment: Do you know how big 300! is?

Comment: Are you trying to build [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning)?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, Yes, it has over 615 digits. That is the problem here. Some permutations are far more likely than others and others are impossible all together. I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem computaionally. My take was to denote all found combinations as strings and to simply count them. I edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @ayhan Hi, no that is not my idea here. Though I understand your line of thining.

Comment: I take you actually want combinations, or, subsets in general. There are 2^300 possibilities, which is still way too many, but it's not the same as permutations... What is exactly the result you need? The number cases where any given subset of columns appear?

Comment: @jdehesa Sorry for not being precise enough. I want to know, how often each combination like ? `apple == 1 & orange==1 & kiwi==1`  or `apple == 1 & orange==0 & kiwi==1`  appear. However, I have roughly 300 columns.

Comment: @Rachel You just want a count of each permutation? What is your desired output for this dataframe, could you clarify that please?

Comment: Is it also necessary to be able to count things like `apple == 1 & orange==1 & kiwi==whatever`? Or all the queries will specify a value for all the columns?

Comment: You you looking for something like `df_apple.iloc[:, 1:].apply(tuple,1).value_counts()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this fits your needs:

```
import pandas as pd

df_apple = pd.DataFrame({'_id':    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                         'apple':  ['1', '0', '1'],
                         'orange': ['1', '1', '0'],
                         'kiwi':   ['1', '0', '1']})

df_counts = df_apple.groupby(by=tuple(df_apple.columns[1:])).count()
idx_str = [[df_counts.index.names[i] for i, v in enumerate(idx) if v != '0']
           for idx in df_counts.index]
idx_str = [" and ".join((", ".join(s[:-1]), s[-1])) if len(s) > 1 else s[0] for s in idx_str]
df_counts.index = idx_str
df_counts.columns = ["count"]
df_counts = df_counts.T

print(df_counts)
>>>        orange  apple and kiwi  apple, kiwi and orange
    count       1               1                       1
```

Comment: That is already quite useful but does not give me the desired output. Could I create a table showing me all subsets and how often they are found automatically?

Comment: Thank you! That seems perfect!